# CacheImageNetwork cache not working Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using the [cache_image_network](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image) plugin in my flutter to cache images from the network.

Unfortunately it doesn't work and i can see this "warning" :

```
I/flutter ( 4308): *** WARNING ***
I/flutter ( 4308): 
I/flutter ( 4308): Invalid argument null with type Null.
I/flutter ( 4308): Only num, String and Uint8List are supported. See https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/blob/master/sqflite/doc/supported_types.md for details
I/flutter ( 4308): 
I/flutter ( 4308): This will throw an exception in the future. For now it is displayed once per type.
```

The url i provide is working fine, i can see my image from the network but the cache has this issue (i have turned off my internet connection & restarted the app, no image in cache).

How can i fix this please ?

I am using the latest version (at the moment this question is asked) 3.0.0 of the plugin.

EDIT : I am adding the code in case it matters :

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CachedNetworkImage(
      imageUrl: url,
      maxWidthDiskCache: 200,
      maxHeightDiskCache: 200,
      placeholderFadeInDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 100),
      placeholder: (context, url) => SvgPicture.asset(
        'assets/images/Logo/logo_login_light.svg',
        width: Constants.maxHeight * 10 / 100,
        height: Constants.maxHeight * 10 / 100,
      ),
      imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) => Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
          image: DecorationImage(
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
              image: imageProvider
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

UPDATE :

My question is partially wrong because the CacheNetworkManager is partially working, i was using the resize attribute (200x200) which was caching 2 files :

Here are the cached files :
One of them has null properties.

[image: DB inspector screenshot]

HOWEVER : After i turn off the internet connection and rebuild my app (hot reload or manual restart without IDE), i can see the cache is cleared instead of being read.

Why this behaviour ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i have found the issue, i was calling myself a new instance of the `DefaultCacheManager` class somewhere else in my app and it was causing the trouble (deleting the cache of the CacheNetworkImage)...

As weird as it is, it may help others !

Answer (score 0):

Good day.. were you able to declare the value for the url variable you're using on the imageUrl property...

if not add the value on the url variable or better yet input the network image's url on the imageUrl property directly..

Comment: Yes, i simply pass it in the Constructor of my Widget class that wraps this CacheNetworkImageWidget.
It works fine because i can the photo fading in the widget when i am online, but the caching system seems to fail.

Comment: Good Day... if ever you're still having problems in caching images do try using NetworkImage class and Image.network() both do cached images.

Here's a link that might help you when you try Image.network() : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7oIAs-0G4mw

Comment: Thanks for the link, and the Image.network has indeed a cacheHeight and cacheWidth property. However it does not cache anything as i turn off the internet connection and restart the app (without rebuild). Also, i am not able where is the cached file in the Database Inspector of Android studio...